# What's the best way to handle large files upload with aiohttp (server)

Tags: python, python-3.x, upload, aiohttp

I'm currently working on kind of cloud files manager. You can basically upload your files through a website. This website is connected to a python backend which will store your files and manage them using a database. It will basically put every of your files inside a folder and rename them with their hash. The database will associate the name of the file and its categories (kindof folders) with the hash so that you can retrieve the file easily.
My problem is that I would like the file upload to be really user friendly: I have a quite bad connection and when I try to download or upload a file on the internet I often get problems like at 90% of file uploading, the upload fails and I need to restart it. I'ld like to avoid that.

I'm using aiohttp to achieve this, how could I allow a file to be uploaded in multiple times? What should I use to upload large files.
In a previous code which managed really small files (less than 10MB), I was using something like that:

```py
data = await request.post()
data['file'].file.read()
```

Should I continue to do it this way for large files?